# How to auto refresh requesting data and refresh variables shown in html?

Tags: python, html, websocket, refresh, tornado

so basically i am using python request post to grab data about next bus arriving time, then i used websocket and tornado to make a html webpage to show the data that i grabbed.

However, i really dont know how to auto refresh the data and the html. I tried to use this:

```
import threading
def getETA():
threading.Timer(5.0, getETA).start()
```

... the python file ends with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.listen(8888)
  ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
getETA()
```

so the code run and showing this error

```
Exception in thread Thread-25:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 1186, in run
   self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Tan\Desktop\DIP\DIP WEB INTERFACE\testing.py", line 183, in getETA
   app.listen(8888)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1788, in listen
   server.listen(port, address)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 126, in listen
   sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 187, in bind_sockets
   sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Please suggest correct way or other method to let my html local host show refreshed value.

Comment: what's up with your indentation?  why is `getETA()` not indented in your script?